# PHP: почему не удаляется cookie?

Tags: php

Если я прописал в php коде такое:

```
setcookie("Hello", "Привет!");
echo $_COOKIE["Hello"];
```

И мне выводит Привет!

Но после того как я прописал

```
unset($_COOKIE["Hello"]);
echo $_COOKIE["Hello"];
```

И все стало норм мне не вывело Привет! И после того как я убрал `unset` мне снова вывело Привет! Как убить кукис что бы он опять не выводился больше?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы не назначаете cookie время жизни, то она становится сессионной и действует до момента, пока пользователь не выключит браузер. Уничтожать ее только на сервере бесполезно, нужно заставить браузер стереть ее и не отправлять больше при помощи HTTP-заголовка Set-Cookie.

Поэтому чтобы уничтожить сессионную cookie ей необходимо выставить время жизни совпадающее с текущим или более раннее время - в этом случае браузер уничтожит ее на своей стороне и не будет отправлять HTTP-заголовок Set-Cookie, который инициализирует значение в массиве `$_COOKIE`

```
setcookie("Hello", "", time() - 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что $_COOKIE - это суперглобальная переменная всего лишь. и вы удаляете его. А не куки брайзера.

А что бы удалить куки браузера, нужно им установить прошлое время.

Answer (score 1):

Для установки печеньки в браузер, необходимо добавить время её жизни.

Если время истечёт, браузер сам удалит её.
Чтобы не ждать истечения времени, можно установить время `-1`

```
setcookie("Hello", "Привет", time() + 3600, '/');
setcookie("Hello", null, -1, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Открыть cookie

```
$hello = 'Hello!';
setcookie('hello', $hello, 2147483647, '/');
echo $hello;
```

Закрыть cookie

```
setcookie('hello', $hello, -2147483647, '/');
echo $hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже нашел спасибо всем))))

```
setcookie ("Hello", "", time() - 3600);
```

Comment: Зачем устанавливать время от текущего в минус час? Правильно нужно писать, а не костыли